# How to access Twitter's OpenAPI?

Tags: twitter, openapi

I'm trying to access Twitter's OpenAPI, which I believe is found here: https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/openapi.json

When I do this, I keep getting error 131:

[image]

- Is this the correct uri to access it?
- Am I maybe missing something, like a querystring param?

BTW, [Error 131 is an "internal" version of HTTP Error 500](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this openapi from Twitter:

https://api.twitter.com/2/openapi.json

The resource is from here: https://github.com/twitterdev

Comment: This is the correct URL. The /labs/ URL is no longer available because Labs was retired.